# How can we build an array of dynamic bitset

Tags: c++

How can we build an array of dynamic bitset.

for example:

```
unsigned long long sd=5;
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bitarry[x]=(sd,"NULL");
```

1- lenght bitarry be calculated separately.

2- content bitarry determin within loop.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution when you need an array of length computed at run-time, is to use `std::vector`.